# dxf to shp conversion areas mismatch

Tags: qgis

I have added a dxf file in QGIS and saved it as shp file. the problem it that the area of the the polygon in shp. file is 1% more than the area of polygon in dxf. just to double check i have exported the same shp. file into dxf. and check the area. the difference still exists. can someone please explain.

Comment: Can you add which coordinate system you are working with?

Comment: Or post the actual shapefile somewhere.

Comment: most probably the CRS. Help us to help you if you could share your data.